# GeoDjango - lon/lat PointFields distance are using geometry instead of geography

Tags: python, django, geolocation, distance, geodjango

I'm trying to use GeoDjango to store lat/lon in a `PointField` and then query the distance between two `PointField`s in kilometres. Something is not working to cause the distance calculation to return the geometric distance rather than the geographic distance. I'm using `geography=True` in the model but it doesn't seem to help. I'm using `postgis` and `postgresql`

Models:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models

class Customer(models.Model):
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    gis_location = models.PointField(u"longitude/latitude",
                                     geography=True, 
                                     blank=True, 
                                     null=True)
```

Test:

```
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point

# some set up

customer1.gis_location = Point(-79.3, 43.6)
print('Customer 1:', customer1.gis_location)

customer2.gis_location = Point(-89.2, 48.4)
print('Customer 2:', customer2.gis_location)

distance = customer1.gis_location.distance(customer2.gis_location)
print('Distance: ', distance)
```

Output:

```
Customer 1:  SRID=4326;POINT (-79.2999999999999972 43.6000000000000014)  
Customer 2:  SRID=4326;POINT (-89.2000000000000028 48.3999999999999986)  
Distance: 11.002272492535353
```

This is returning just the geometric distance between two points instead of the geographic distance. Does anyone have any advice for how I can get this to return KMs distance on a spheroid?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Reading through the documentation I found that this distance calculation in the GEOSGeometry class does not respect the SRID and is different than the one provided directly by the PostGIS database.

I used the python libray [geopy](http://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/1.11.0/) which provides the `distance` method for calculating distance.

```
from geopy.distance import distance as geopy_distance
geopy_distance(customer1.gis_location, customer2.gis_location).kilometers
```

Unfortunately I still can't figure out how to do a distance calculation with two `Point`s using Django's GIS library.